# How to enable only the current and future dates in 2 cutoff days?

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-modal

The black circle are the 2 cutoffdays and the red 1 is the current date for example only.

So I wanted to enable the 15,16,17 dates (to be clickable only); 
I already disabled the weekends.

[image]

Comment: you want to unable 2 day from current day excluding week ends??? ans for week end  you consider saturday and sunday both?

Comment: yes, 15, 16, ,17 should be clickable, 18 and 19 is already disabled. because its part of weekend that i already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help you solve your problem.

```js
$('input').datepicker({
  minDate: 0,
  maxDate: '+1w-3D',
  beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <p>Date:
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
  </p>
</body>
```